# Этимология слова "халява"

Tags: этимология

Откуда пошло слово "халява" и что оно изначально значило?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На этот счет есть несколько версий. По одной это слово происходит от названия некоторых несложных работ (и в стекольном деле, и в сапожном), по другой - "халявой" называли носимую за голенищем сапога ложку, с которой можно было пристроиться к любой раздаче еды.
Теперь "халява" - это синоним дармовщины, легкого успеха.

Answer (score -1):

Воровская лексика происходит из идиша или иврита.

"шмон" - обыск в одесских тюрьмах традиционно происходил в 8 вечера, а "шмОне" на иврите как раз означает "восемь"
"мусор" (не мент) от слова "масар" - что-то типа охранника
"халява" - "халав" - молоко
"малина" - "млина" - тайное место для ночевки

лох, шухер, чувак, пацан, хавать, мухлевать...